# redux-undo that wraps all slices in RTK?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am implementing redux-undo library introduced in redux docs in my RTK project. The example in the docs guides you to wrap single slice (or reducer) to make it 'undoable'.

```
// todos.js
import undoable from 'redux-undo'

/* ... */

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  /* ... */
}

const undoableTodos = undoable(todos)

export default undoableTodos
```

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import visibilityFilter from './visibilityFilter'

const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
})

export default todoApp
```

> You may wrap one or more reducers in undoable at any level of the reducer composition hierarchy. We choose to wrap todos instead of the top-level combined reducer so that changes to visibilityFilter are not reflected in the undo history.

This example, as described above, only restores changes in `todos` slice. Anything happened to `visibilityFilter` is not undoable.
What I want is to wrap the entire store with undoable() so that with one `undo()` function call, you can revoke all changes to the store.

Below is my attempt in redux toolkit and I want to know if this is the right way to go.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import undoable from 'redux-undo'

import todoSlice from "../features/todo/todoSlice";
import visibilityFilterSlice from "../features/visibilityFilter/visibilityFilterSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    todos: todoSlice,
    visibilityFilter: visibilityFilterSlice,
  },
});

export default undoable(store);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your attempt wraps the store instance, not a reducer - redux-undo won't know what to make of that. Try this instead (using `combineReducers` with RTK is totally fine):

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todos: todoSliceReducer,
    visibilityFilter: visibilityFilterSliceReducer,
  })

const undoableRootReducer = undoable(rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: undoableRootReducer,
});
```

For TypeScript it is important not to do `reducer: undoable(rootReducer),`, but to do this in a variable declaration above the `configureStore` call.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and tell you how it worked!

Comment: it works nice and clean. For anyone implementing this code, keep in mind that when you select you must do `state.present.todos`, not `state.todos.present`.

Comment: Something must be wrong in this code. You pass reducers to `combineReducers`, not slice objects from `createSlice`, right?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov I was just reusing the variable names that OP used, but I'll add a `reducer` at the end to make it easier for others to read.